# using FutureBuilder to get Future<String> from firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, future, builder

This is my code in which I want to display an email which is a Future and I will get it from my firestore.However, I am not sure how I will need to retrieve my value using FutureBuilder which I want to use as a string.

This is my method to get my email:

```
Future<String> getEmail() async {
    String _email = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).email;
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firestore.collection('users')
      .document(_email)
      .collection('met_with')
      .document('email')
      .get();
    // print("data: ${snapshot.data}"); // might be useful to check
    return snapshot.data['email']; // or another key, depending on how it's saved
  }
```

this is my updated code:

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage(imagePath),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        title: Text(
          email,
          style: TextStyle(
            c  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 3.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage(imagePath),
        ),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        title: Text(
          email,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.deepPurple[700],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(infection),
        onTap: () => showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (builder) {

              return FutureBuilder(
                future: getEmail(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }else{
                    return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                     child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    BottomSheetText(
                        question: 'Email', result:  snapshot.data['email']),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    BottomSheetText(
                        question: 'Contact Time',result:"lol"),// getTimeStamp().toString()),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    BottomSheetText(
                        question: 'Contact Location',
                        result: "help"),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    BottomSheetText(question: 'Times Contacted', result: "lool",),
                  ],
                  ),


                     );
                  }
                }else{
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();}
                }








                     );




            }
        ),





                ),
              );



  }
}
```

Here is my firebase database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PngNq.png)

Comment: can you add firebase database screenshot ?

Comment: done and updated my code

Answer (score 4):

Your query is wrong, try following one.

```
Future<String> getEmail() async {
    String _email = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).email;
    var a = await Firestore.instance
            .collection("met_with")
            .where('email', isEqualTo:.  _email )
            .getDocuments();
     return a.documents[0]['email'];
}
```

And to call this method you need futureBuilder.

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getEmail(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }else{
               return Center( // here only return is missing
                  child: Text(snapshot.data['email'])
                );
              }
            }else if (snapshot.hasError){
              return Text('no data');
            }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
```

Comment: @OHajj can you test now ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `FutureBuilder`:

```
           FutureBuilder(
                future: getEmail(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }else{
                   return Center( // here only return is missing
                      child: Text(snapshot.data['email'])
                    );
                  }
                }else if (snapshot.hasError){
                  Text('no data');
                }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
```

This way you can use the returned value of the method inside the `build` method. Also change the `Future` method to the following:

```
Future<String> getEmail() async {
    String _email = (await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()).email;
    return await _firestore.collection('users')
      .document(_email)
      .collection('met_with')
      .document('email')
      .get();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but where exactly should I place the FutureBuilder in my code?

Comment: instead of `Padding` use `FutureBuilder` then use the `padding` here `else{
                   Center(
                      child: Text(snapshot.data['email'])
                    );
                  }`

Comment: and how do i call the getEmail() method in my BottomSheetText knowing it only accepts a String value?

Comment: getEmail is called in futurebuilder, in bottomsheettext u retrieve the string `snapshot.data['email']

Comment: and is it just the bottomsheettext that is using the email that i should include? or should i include all the other bottomsheettexts as well in the padding?

Comment: sorry for bothering but for some reason the circular indicator keeps infinitely looping without showing data

Comment: @OHajj try now.