# Flutter firestore document counter display problem

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm a bit inexperienced with Firebase data output I have a query in firestore for a data counter in a collection it looks like this (taken and slightly corrected from the official documentation)

```
final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
fs.collection("users").count().get().then((users) => print('${users.count}'),
);
```

Help with its output in Text() Classical output of specific data from a collection is clear to me, but here any attempt leads me into a stupor, I am not a very strong expert in Flutter and would like to see a small example of how I can implement it

Comment: Since `fs.collection("users").count().get()` returns a `Future`, you'll want to look at how to use a `FutureBuilder` to display the value in the UI. Similar (not same) to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61751973

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, what worked for me was

```
    final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final Future<AggregateQuerySnapshot> documents =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').count().get();
```

```
FutureBuilder<AggregateQuerySnapshot>(
              future: documents,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AggregateQuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                late Text text;
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  text = Text('Total Users: ${snapshot.data!.count.toString()}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: appColorYellow));
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  text = Text("Error");
                } else {
                  text = Text("Loading");
                }
                return Center(child: text);
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Future Builder :
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

```dart
final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final future = await fs.collection("users").count().get(); 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: future, 
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
         late Text text;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
             text = Text(snapshot.data.count.toString()) ; 
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            text = Text("Error"); 
          } else {
            text = Text("Loading"):
          }
          return Center(
            child: text
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everything works, I've been through seven circles of hell until you helped me find a solution.

Comment: Check out my version