# Flutter FireStore get() function is not being initialized

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
String? postid;
  bool Iliked = false;
  getLikedDoc() async {
    var a = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(postid)
        .collection('postlikes')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
        .get();
    Iliked = (a.exists == true) ? true : false;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLikedDoc();
  }
```

when I test above code, it does not initialize when I view the post however when I place the getLikedDoc()function when the user likes it, it works.

How can I change the code so that it does initialize when the user reviews the post?

Comment: Just an aside but "Iliked" is not a good name for an instance rather than a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using `Iliked` in your `build` method to render its value.

In that case, the field **is** actually getting initialized. But since data is loaded from Firestore asynchronous, your UI is initially rendered with the `false` value - and you never tell the UI that it needs to be updated.

One proper way to handle such asynchronous values is by [using a `StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and calling `setState` at the end of `getLikedDoc`.

Alternatively you can use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), which encapsulates all of that for you. For an example of this, see [using FutureBuilder to get Future<String> from firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61748357/using-futurebuilder-to-get-futurestring-from-firestore).
The Firebase documentation shows a more advanced version of that, which [uses a `Stream`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart) which means that it also automatically shows changes to the document.

Comment: Thank you @Frank - that's right! I didn't have any luck with calling the setState within Stateful widget. I already have 1 Streambuilder and 1 Futurebuilder within the build widget. I tried having one more Futurebuilder but saw bunch of errors. Do you know if there is an example of having 2 Futurebuilders or is that not a good practice?

Comment: First off: does the first part of my answer explain why your current code doesn't work?

There's nothing inherently different about using multiple `FutureBuilder`s and or `StreamBuilder`s, but there's definitely many mistakes you could make along the way. If it is clear from my answer why your current code won't work, I recommend posting a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you are now stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's useful) and any error message you may be getting.

Comment: It does. Thanks Frank.